# The given name was not found in the service operations

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wcf-data-services

**This is my code:**

```
// This method is called only once to initialize service-wide policies.
public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
{
    // TODO: set rules to indicate which entity sets and service operations are visible, updatable, etc.
    // Examples:
    config.SetServiceOperationAccessRule("getSMSs", ServiceOperationRights.All);
    config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V3;
}
public IQueryable<SM> getSMSs()
{
    SelfServiceEntities db = new SelfServiceEntities();
    return from d in db.SMS select d;
}
```

**I got this exception:**

```
The given name 'getSMSs' was not found in the service operations.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to define your method as [service operation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744841%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
[WebGet]
public IQueryable<SM> getSMSs()
{
```

Comment: It works, thanks a lot. I have one more question. I want to build my webservices using WCF Data service. so, is all what i need is to make functions like `getSMSs` ? and call it? i do know that I have to define the entities that i should work with. but i am asking about the architucure. don't i need classes ?